# Simplify this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Simplify this complex number modulus

$$\left|\left(\frac{100\pi i}{100+100\pi i}\right)\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)\right|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left|\left(\frac{100\pi i}{100+100\pi i}\right)\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$\left|\left(\frac{\frac{100\pi i}{100}}{\frac{100+100\pi i}{100}}\right)\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$\left|\left(\frac{\pi i}{1+\pi i}\right)\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$\left|\frac{3\sqrt{2}\pi i}{1+\pi i}\right|=$$
$$\frac{\left|3\sqrt{2}\pi i\right|}{\left|1+\pi i\right|}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{0^2+\left(3\sqrt{2}\pi\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1^2+\pi^2}}=$$
$$\frac{3\sqrt{2}\pi}{\sqrt{1+\pi^2}}=3\pi \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\pi^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the numerator and denominator inside the "modulus" by $100-(100\pi)i$.

The denominator then becomes $(100)^2+(100\pi)^2$. Simplify further by factoring $(100)^2$.